# How to free the memory taken by a pyspark model (JavaModel)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, nlp, word2vec

As described, I load a trained word2vec model through pyspark.

```
word2vec_model = Word2VecModel.load("saving path")
```

After using that, I want to delete it since it will take much memory space on single node (I used the findSynonyms function, and the doc says it should be local used only)
I tried to use

```
del word2vec_model
gc.collect()
```

but it seems that doesn't word. And it's not an rdd file, I can't use .unpersist(). I didn't find any like unload() fuction in the doc.

Anyone could help me or give me some advice?

Comment: What makes you think the `del` didn't work? (What's the evidence that the model is still around?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ensure that the object is dereferenced by the py4j gateway by running the following statement:

Given `word2vec_model` a pyspark `Transformer`:

- Given `spark` a `SparkSession`:

```py
spark.sparkContext._gateway.detach(word2vec_model._java_obj)
```

- ... or given `sc` a `SparkContext`:

```py
sc._gateway.detach(word2vec_model._java_obj)
```

Explanations:

1. **Access underlying wrapper object**: Your model is a pyspark `Transformer` and each transformer holds an instance of `JavaObject` in a private `_java_obj` attribute.
2. **Access the `SparkContext`'s py4j gateway**.
3. Use the gateway's `detach` method on the wrapper object (instance of `JavaObject`)